# Is there an FAA definition of what "normal flight operation" means?

Tags: faa-regulations

Some documents talk about normal and abnormal operation. Is there a definition by FAA what normal operation is?

Comment: Your question is about normal and abnormal procedures, or about weather conditions, or about something else. Please may be you may develop the question

Comment: They way it is used, it seems to distinguish between normal and abnormal operation (so the way the airplane is flown) based on whether or not failure scenarios (e.g. one engine out) apply. Usually in design you only need to consider one failure scenario at a time, hence for the assessment you would assume "normal" operation.  Question is if the term is defined or if the use of that term is ambigious.

Comment: Can you give us more details about the documents, and include a quote from one of them? That might help to give you a useful answer.

Comment: VTC as needing more details, i.e. examples of the "some documents" referenced at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a specific FAA definition of “normal operations” as what is normal will depend on what you’re doing, what you are flying, the condition at the time.  I think for all intents and purposes that normal operations are what the Pilot Operating Handbook states for a given aircraft as outlined in the Normal Procedures section. Outside of that I would have to consider normal operations is anything following the FAR/AIM for a given flight or flight maneuver.  For example, following the preferred method of entering a traffic pattern at a non-towered airport would be considered normal operations.